# Windows 10 CU proxy on LAN setting cannot be change

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, proxy, windows-10-v1703

I cannot change proxy on LAN setting in Windows 10 Creators Update (CU) (with the latest update). The OK button is not working; it's stuck on LAN setting window. Only the Cancel button is working. So I cannot change proxy on my PC any more. Is there any way to fix it?
I have tried restarting my PC several times, and cleaned my registry with CCleaner. But it does not fix anything.

[image]

Comment: try to set the setting via the setting apps. Simply search for proxy

Comment: Can you [change the proxy settings from a command prompt using the reg command](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2016/12/16#change_proxy)? Or by using Microsoft's [Registry Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registry_editor#Registry_editors)? The [Windows proxy server settings](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/settings/) are under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` in the Windows Registry.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and using Proxy Settings under Windows 10's Settings does not work either (and Fiddler can no longer set the proxy programmatically).

I'm guessing it is caused by a recent Windows Update (issue started after I installed updates on 6/29/17).  I reset Windows (to solve a different issue involving Visual Studio crashing at startup) and the problem with LAN Settings / Proxy Server not being editable went away.

There's no group policy (that I can see at least) or registry setting causing this and no policy or registry setting I've tried could fix it (in my case LAN Settings button on inetcpl.cpl was grayed out - modifying the registry allowed it to be editable but as you said the OK button continued to do nothing).

If you can roll back updates incrementally I'd try that otherwise reset Windows and apply all but the latest updates. To reset Windows back up your data and then hold shift key and click Power and choose restart, then follow the startup UI to reset.

Comment: I have this problem on another machine and I used Windows All in One to clean registry and fix windows.  It fixed it only temporarily, which leaves me to believe something in the domain login process is to blame. The LAN Settings button in ietcpl.cpl becomes grayed out and Fiddler can't set the proxy.. Manual registry changes can enable the button but this just reveals the issue. Maybe this is a combination of security/login settings and a bug in Windows or a Windows update.

Answer (score 0):

Win10 1703 if the service "WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service" is disabled then proxy settings do not get set. If it’s set to manual then every time IE is launch the service starts up and proxy
is set. Same with Automatic.